# How could i find out if a webView has a previous page?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a webView and an actionbar on it. I have added a previous page menuitem that would do a

```
webView.goBack();
```

Is there anyway to find out if a previous page exists to actually go back ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please reffere to android's documentation of WebView.

According to the website you can call:

```
webView.canGoBack();
```

to check if your webview has a previous page (can go back).

For more please check this link: [WebView Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#canGoBack%28%29)